# Sobre jasper IReports, preciso ordernar colunas quem vem do banco de dados para serem exibidas ordenadas no relatório

Tags: java, jasper-reports

O problema que já ordenei pelo iReport ide, query sql na string da classe clienteDAO, mas meu chefe quer que ordene com uma das classes do jars do Jasper, eu estou procurando sem sucesso. Alguém já passou por isso?

Eu só quero ordernar o relatório que o java gera e preciso utilizar algum método de alguma classe do jar do jasper.

grata...

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mande mais detalhes.

Comment: Não sei se vai ajudar, mais no 'Dataset and Query' do JasperDesigner tem uma aba chamada Sorting, lá você pode adicionar 'Fields' para que eles sejam ordenados. Você pode selecionar mais de um e selecionar a ordem de ordenação.

Comment: preciso fazer isso no eclipse com código java.

Comment: Você esta enviando uma lista para alimentar seu relatorio?

Comment: Sim, uma lista que vem do banco.

Comment: ME AJUDAAAAAAAA

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42889/discussion-between-julio-cesar-da-silva-barros-and-gonz).

Answer (score 1):

Tente dar uma olhada nesse link:

https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/building-dynamic-columns-in-jasperrepor-1

Ele exemplifica a criação de colunas dinamicas com o **jar** [Dynamic Jasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/).

Eu já utilizei para resolver um problema parecido com o seu (no meu caso, dependendo da consulta, eu precisava adicionar ou remover colunas no relatório). A implementação não é tão simples, por isso para utilizar você vai precisar dar uma estudada em alguns exemplos.